# Is this the proper way of using Mutex lock and Atomic types in rust to find the parallel sum of an arrray?

Tags: multithreading, rust

I've written Rust code to compute the sum of array elements in parallel by breaking it into chunks. I utilized Mutex, Arc, and Threads. Here's the code. I want to confirm if I'm using Mutex, Arc, and Threads correctly, as per Rust documentation. They recommend using threads to create processes and atomic data types for thread safety. Mutex safeguards shared data by allowing only one thread to access it at a time. Please let me know if I'm using Arc and Mutex correctly and suggest any corrections. The code compiles and runs, but I'm uncertain about lock usage.

```
#![allow(non_snake_case)]
#![allow(unused_variables)]
#![allow(unused_imports)]
#![allow(dead_code)]

extern crate num_cpus;

use std::env::args;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread;

fn spawn_thread(array: &Arc<Mutex<Vec<i32>>>, sum: &Arc<Mutex<i32>>, chunk_per_thread: usize, start_idx: usize, end_idx: usize, thread_vec: &mut Vec<thread::JoinHandle<()>>) {
    let pointer_to_arc_array = Arc::clone(array);
    let pointer_to_sum = Arc::clone(sum);
    let thread = thread::spawn(move || {
        let arr_lock = pointer_to_arc_array.lock().unwrap();
        let chunk_sum = arr_lock[start_idx..end_idx].iter().sum::<i32>();
        let mut sum_lock = pointer_to_sum.lock().unwrap();
        *sum_lock += chunk_sum;
    });
    thread_vec.push(thread);
}

fn main() {
    let argv: Vec<String> = args().collect();
    let capacity: usize = argv.len() - 1;
    let mut array: Vec<i32> = Vec::with_capacity(capacity);
    array.extend(argv.iter().skip(1).filter_map(|elem| elem.parse::<i32>().ok()));
    let thread_num = num_cpus::get();
    let chunk_per_thread: usize = capacity / thread_num;
    let array = Arc::new(Mutex::new(array));
    let mut thread_vec = Vec::with_capacity(thread_num);
    let sum = Arc::new(Mutex::new(0i32));
    let loop_count = thread_num - 1;
    // Create threads
    for i in 0..loop_count {
        let start_idx: usize = i * chunk_per_thread;
        spawn_thread(&array, &sum, chunk_per_thread, start_idx, start_idx + chunk_per_thread, &mut thread_vec);
    }
    spawn_thread(&array, &sum, chunk_per_thread, loop_count * chunk_per_thread, capacity, &mut thread_vec);
    // Wait for all threads to finish
    for thread in thread_vec {
        thread.join().unwrap();
    }
    // Obtain and print the parallel sum
    let parallel_sum = sum.lock().unwrap();
    println!("Parallel sum: {:?}", *parallel_sum);
}
```

Comment: Well you're not doing **any** work in parallel. You have to release the `*_lock`s during the work for that to happen, but you only drop them at the end of each thread.

Comment: How can I release the lock?

Comment: `drop` the `MutexGuard`, but neither `Arc` nor `Mutex` are really the right tool to use here.

Comment: In an ideal scenario what module from rust std wud be ideal for this operation?

Comment: Dunno, ideal heavily depends and is quite subjective in production `rayon`, for this toy problem probably an `AtomicI32` for the sum and `std::thread::scope`d threads.